# Restangular - ExtendAllModels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I would like to extend all Restangular models with a custom function. Is that possible? I don't want to go one model by one...

The function I have in mind would allow me to load a collection with less code, something like `object.loadCollection('collectionName')` and that would do something like

```
object.getList('collectionName').then(function(collectionObjects){
  object['collectionName'] = collectionObjects;
})
```

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are looking for is an element transformer. This allows the decoration of elements at a given route. There is also setOnElementRestangularized which is more global.

```
Restangular. addElementTransformer('collectionName', function (collection) {
    collection.methodName = function () {
        // do stuff
    };
});
```

This would attach the method methodName to collections fetched from the collectionName endpoint.

see: [Add Element Transformer](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addelementtransformer)

Comment: Thanks Brandon! I don't think addElementTransformer is what I'm looking for but setOnElementRestangularized might do the trick.